# Inner join two data sets using Apache Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two data sets (1M unique string) and (1B unique string); I want to know how many strings are common in both sets, and wondering what is the most efficient way to get the number using Apache Pig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first join both the file like below:

```
A = LOAD '/joindata1.txt' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
B = LOAD '/joindata2.txt' AS (b1:int,b2:int);
X = JOIN A BY a1, B BY b1;
```

Then you can count the number of rows :

```
grouped_records = GROUP X ALL;
count_records = FOREACH grouped_records GENERATE COUNT(A.a1);
```

Does it help you problem...

Comment: @LinMa If this answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your case doesn't fall under either replicate or merge or skewed join. So you have to do a default join, where in map phase it annotates each record's source, Join  key would be used as the shuffle key so that the same join key goes to same reducer then the leftmost input is cached in memory in the reducer side and the other input is passed through to do a join. You could also improve your join by normal join optimizations like filter NULL's before joining and table which has the largest number of tuples per key could be kept as the last table in your query.

Comment: why in my case it does not fall into replicate or merge or skewed join?

Comment: If you have to do a replicate join then one of your dataset has to be small in terms of KB so that it could be sent to all task trackers and that would be cached in memory and your other dataset would be passed through to do the join. But here none of your dataset seems to be small. Skewed join would be used if you have mutiple values for a particular key in such a way that a single reducer is not able to hold more data. But here your dataset contains unique string values. You could use merge join if your dataset is sorted.

Comment: what means merged join? And could you share some documents on basics how Skewed join works internally?

Comment: Small data set can be a couple of MBs in size, it all depends on how much memory is allocated to the YARN container, try out the replicated join and if  you do not get memory related exceptions, than it is all good. You could also use  Bloom Filters, see http://integralads.com/tech-corner/pig-and-joining-data/

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already sorted in both the data sets you can define `merged join`.

```
Mergede = join A by a1, B by b1 USING "merge";

Skewed Join: If the data is skewed and user need finer control over the allocation to reducers.

skewedh = join A by a1, B by b1 USING "skewed";
```

Comment: wondering how skewed join working underlying to under skewed data scenario? Thanks.